# defined class and function not recognized

Tags: python, django, django-models

I defined a board object as follow:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    #let's do the relational part after I've done the other fields
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    #where I got the image https://mixkit.co/blog/trello-backgrounds-awesome-free-illustrations-for- 
    trello-boards/
    ImageUrl = models.URLField(
    default="https://mixkit.imgix.net/art/preview/mixkit-starry-night-sky-over-hills-and-water-85- 
    original-large.png?q=80&auto=format%2Ccompress&h=700&q=80&dpr=1",
    blank=True, null=False)

    CreatedAt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    EndsAt = Board.return_date_time_in_one_year()

    def __str__(self):
         return self.title

    def return_date_time_in_one_year(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now + timedelta(years=1)
```

When I try to migrate I get the following error, I'm not sure where I went wrong in how I defined the classes, I'm new to both python and django.

```
 File "C:\Users\Ameer\Documents\GitHub\Squasha_trello_clone\squasha\board\models.py", line 16, 
 in Board
 EndsAt = Board.return_date_time_in_one_year()
 NameError: name 'Board' is not defined
```

Comment: You want `self.return_date...`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need to go back to the tutorials and repeat the basics of Python classes.  You haven't yet assimilated the differences between class attributes and instance attributes, as well as the code associated with each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inside the class Board. Therefore, you refer inside the Board class to itself using `this`.

The line `Board.return_date_time_in_one_year()` would then become `self.return_date_time_in_one_year()`

Comment: EndsAt = self.return_date_time_in_one_year()

NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Now I'm getting this instead

Comment: @user3718247 put it inside your `__init__` method

Comment: Check out the documentation for Python classes. As @PaulH suggests, indeed that is your problem as you try to reference to something which is not created yet.